# Rospy isn't catching KeyboardInterrupt on the second iteration of the loop

Tags: python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written a publisher in Python to publish joint angles to a simple robot. The program only catches KeyboardInterrupt on the very first loop before I've ever published anything. However, as soon as I enter the X&Y values and the code does its thing, it stops responding to KeyboardInterrupt. The programs doesn't publish after I press Ctrl+C but it doesn't quit either. I'm quite stumped, any help would be appreciated. TIA

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import math
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
import time


def main():
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            #~ joint = raw_input('Enter joint: ')
            #~ angle =2 float(raw_input('Enter angle in radians: '))
            #~ command(joint,angle)
            x = float(raw_input("Enter end effector X in meters: "))
            y = float(raw_input("Enter end effector Y in meters: "))
            angles = ik(x,y)
            th1 = angles[0]
            th2 = angles[1]
            print('Angles - Shoulder: %f, Elbow: %f' %(th1,th2))
            command('Shoulder',th1*-1)
            command('Elbow',th2*-1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Process shutting down')
            break
            

def ik(x,y):
    l1 = .390
    l2 = .090

    B = math.sqrt(math.pow(x,2)+math.pow(y,2))
    q1 = math.atan2(y,x)
    q2 = math.acos((math.pow(l1,2)-math.pow(l2,2)+math.pow(B,2))/(2*l1*B))
    th1 = q1+q2
    th2 = math.acos((math.pow(l1,2)+math.pow(l2,2)-math.pow(B,2))/(2*l1*l2))
    return [th1,th2]
        
def command(joint,angle):
    topic = ('camera_arm/%s_position_controller/command' %joint)
    print topic
    pub = rospy.Publisher(topic,Float64,queue_size=1,latch=True)
    rospy.init_node('commander', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    if not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.loginfo('Publishing angle %f to %s joint'% (angle, joint))
        pub.publish(angle)
        rate.sleep()
    return 0

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Edit: jayess suggested that my repeated publisher creation might be an issue so I modified the code as follows but the error persists.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import math
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
import time


def main():
    rospy.init_node('commander', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    shoulder  = rospy.Publisher("camera_arm/Shoulder_position_controller/command",Float64,queue_size=1,latch=True)
    elbow = rospy.Publisher("camera_arm/Elbow_position_controller/command",Float64,queue_size=1,latch=True)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            x = float(raw_input("Enter end effector X in meters: "))
            y = float(raw_input("Enter end effector Y in meters: "))
            angles = ik(x,y)
            th1 = angles[0]
            th2 = angles[1]
            print('Angles - Shoulder: %f, Elbow: %f' %(th1,th2))
                        
            if not rospy.is_shutdown():
                rospy.loginfo('Publishing angle %f to Shoulder joint'% (th1))
                shoulder.publish(th1)
                rate.sleep()
                rospy.loginfo('Publishing angle %f to Elbow joint'% (th2))
                elbow.publish(th2)
                rate.sleep()
                
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Process shutting down')
            break
            

def ik(x,y):
    l1 = .390
    l2 = .090

    B = math.sqrt(math.pow(x,2)+math.pow(y,2))
    q1 = math.atan2(y,x)
    q2 = math.acos((math.pow(l1,2)-math.pow(l2,2)+math.pow(B,2))/(2*l1*B))
    th1 = q1+q2
    th2 = math.acos((math.pow(l1,2)+math.pow(l2,2)-math.pow(B,2))/(2*l1*l2))
    return [th1,th2]
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262560/rospy-isn%27t-catching-keyboardinterrupt-on-the-second-iteration-of-the-loop/) by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-05-25**:
Why are you creating a publisher and starting a node within your `command` function? This means that every time this function is called a publisher will be created and the node will be invited. I have a feeling that this may be part of the issue.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-05-25**:
Try going back to the tutorials and see if you get to the root of the problem.

**Comment by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on 2017-05-25**:
I modified the code and moved the node and publisher out of that function. The error persists. It stops catching KeyboardInterrupt as soon as the node is created.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-05-25**:
What versions of ROS and (I presume) Ubuntu are you using? How are you running your node? E.g., using `rosrun`, `roslaunch`, or some other way? What's ROS telling you? When you say you changed the code, what did you do? Can you post it? The more information you give the better help you can get.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-25**:
This probably isn't your issue, but your implementation of the `rospy.Rate.sleep` function is incorrect. If you want to sleep for 0.1 seconds, use `rospy.sleep(0.1)`. The use of rospy.Rate is controlling the rate of loops. There should only ever be one `rospy.Rate.sleep()` per loop, at the end of it

**Comment by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on 2017-05-25**:
@jayess, I'm sorry, I edited the main question with the updated code. I'm using Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm running it like any other python script using `python`

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-05-25**:
What are your inputs? When I run your edited code I keep getting `ValueError: math domain error` with values between 0.0001 to 5.

**Comment by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on 2017-05-25**:
@jayess, I haven't done a full workspace analysis on this but for now X=0.3 and Y = 0.1 should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now that I think about it, your incorrect use of `rospy.Rate.sleep()` may be the cause. So try this:

- turn both of the `rate.sleep()` calls into `rospy.sleep(0.1)` calls
- change the loop rate to be 0.5 seconds per loop, like `rate = rospy.Rate(2)`
- put `rate.sleep()` at the very end of your while loop, after the try/except block and in-line with it

See if that changes anything. Sleep calls listen for Ctrl+C interrupts. Your loop timing will be all out of whack due to using a loop sleep twice, which may be causing the sleeps to not catch interrupts.

**EDIT:**
Actually, let me alter that a little bit. You don't want a `rospy.Rate.sleep()` call at all here, because its loop timing will be dependent on user input (not good). So just use another `rospy.sleep(1)` or something at the end of your loop to catch Ctrl+C interrupts.

**EDIT 2 (answer):**
The problem may lie in the fact that ROS is handling signals itself, and so a KeyboardInterrupt is never actually raised. Try setting `disable_signals=True` in your node initialization, like `rospy.init_node('commander', anonymous=True, disable_signals=True)`. Disabling signals won't cause any major issues. ROS just uses SIGINT to shut down nodes itself, preventing users to have to explicitly look for and catch KeyboardInterrupt exceptions etc. You're basically doing the same thing yourself.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on 2017-05-25**:
Nope, that didn't fix the issue.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-25**:
When are you attempting to interrupt it? When it is requesting data, or when it is running afterwards?

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-25**:
The problem may lie in the fact that ROS is handling signals itself, and so a KeyboardInterrupt is never actually raised. Try setting `disable_signals=True` in your node initialization, like `rospy.init_node('commander', anonymous=True, disable_signals=True)`

**Comment by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on 2017-05-25**:
Yep. This worked. What repercussions will disabling signals have? If you could just edit the main response, I'll mark it as the answer.